# XPath query issue

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following XML document:

```
<places xmlns="http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/schema.rng" xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" yahoo:start="0" yahoo:count="1" yahoo:total="1">
    <place yahoo:uri="http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/place/23424975" xml:lang="en-US">
        <woeid>23424975</woeid>
        <placeTypeName code="12">Country</placeTypeName>
        <name>United Kingdom</name>
        <country type="Country" code="GB">United Kingdom</country>
        <centroid>
            <latitude>54.314072</latitude>
            <longitude>-2.230010</longitude>
        </centroid>
        <boundingBox>
            <southWest>
                <latitude>49.162090</latitude>
                <longitude>-13.413930</longitude>
            </southWest>
            <northEast>
                    <latitude>60.854691</latitude>
                <longitude>1.768960</longitude>
            </northEast>
        </boundingBox>
       <areaRank>11</areaRank>
       <popRank>0</popRank>
    </place>
</places>
```

I'm trying to capture the "woeid" value. But the XPath query I'm using "/places/place/woeid" doesn't capture it.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify a namespace in your query. How you set up the namespaces depends on your XPath implementation. But you have to declare the `http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/schema.rng` namespace and then use it your path expression. So if you declared it as `yahoo` for example, your XPath expression would look like `/yahoo:places/yahoo:place/yahoo:woeid`.

Alternatively your XPath implementation may allow you to set a default namespace, in which case your original query would work fine.

Keep in mind, because of the `xmlns` attribute without a namespace prefix, all enclosed elements (not otherwise overridden with their own namespace) belong to that namespace (the Yahoo one). So the namespace is really part of the element name. Understanding how namespaces work is really important to using XML.

Answer (score 1):

Set namespace and prefix (e.g. `a`) in your XPath engine, then use:

```
a:places/a:place/a:woeid
```

or simply:

```
*[local-name() = 'places']/*[local-name() = 'place']/*[local-name() = 'woeid']
```